# How to use the output of wdiff (per word diff) to patch a file?

Tags: patch, wdiff

*Is it possible to use the output of [wdiff](https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/) (per word diff) to patch a file?*

I have a file with not only word changes but also added/removed newlines. I can use `wdiff` to view the word changes. But can I apply these word changes back to the original?

I tried something like:

```
wdiff old_file new_file > test.patch
patch old_file test.patch
```

Apparently, this doesn't work (as the newlines are messed up). The output is:

```
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

The question is:

*Is there a variant of `patch` or a similar program that can use the output of `wdiff` (or similar word comparison programs) to patch the changes to the original file?*

(That is, a wdiff/patch process that ignores all changes in newlines).